# Android 5.0 Lollipop is not displaying special characters correctly

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

My Android application is not in English and I was getting some negative feedbacks from the Android Lollipop users that they cannot see special characters correctly.So I checked it by myself on emulator. Below you can see what happens.

The code I use to load font:

```
font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"futura-condensed-medium.ttf");
```

[image]

Here you can see the correct version:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the text? Letters not vertically aligned? Could be a font issue? How text looks with this font on PC (in MS Word, for example)?

Comment: I have added how it should look like. Its not loading the correct font. Also the characters are not in same line. Special characters are belower then others.

Comment: If font is not loaded, then maybe it's not in /assets folder or you forgot to add relative path to the font in assets? E.g. if font is in /assets/fonts/myfont.ttf, then you should `createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/myfont.ttf");`

Comment: the second screenshot is taken from same device but from 4.4. It is working correctly except Lollipop.

Comment: Have you tried other versions of Android to see if the problem is still present? If it's not present in earlier versions, then it's most likely a problem in 5.0. Try 5.0.1 as well. There are a lot of issues with 5.0 and a lot still exist in 5.0.1. If it's only in 5.0 and not in earlier versions or 5.0.1, then it's probably best to just upgrade to 5.0.1 or stick to an earlier version like 4.4.4. If it's present in 5.0.1 as well, I'd report it to Google, if you can't get a fix for it.

Comment: Unfortunately It only occurs in Android Lollipop.

Comment: Have this any updates? I'm having the same issue with a completely different font.

Also this seems to have been reported here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=87794, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=87795

Comment: Where are the characters read from. if they are in an a database you need to check the character encoding of that database or table. One problem i had was with SQLITE when i edited some fields from Ubuntu/Linux the characters whould get an "?" mark instead of the actual character.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling this on your TextView:

```
int flags = textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG;
textView.setPaintFlags(flags);
```